# compare string strcmp() function with 2d pointer of string?

Tags: c, string, 2d, strcmp

i am doing code practicing which is below

```
int main() {


    int N, Q, cnt;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    char **str1=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        str1[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", str1[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d", &Q);
    char **str2=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*Q);
    for(int i=0; i<Q; i++) {
        str2[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", str2[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<Q; i++) {
        for(int j=0, cnt=0; j<N; j++) {
            // if statement 
            if( strcmp(str2[i], str1[j]) == 0) cnt++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", cnt);
    }


    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){    
       free(str1[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<Q; i++) {
       free(str2[i]);
    }
    free(str1); 
    free(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

STD input are

```
4
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
3
aaa
bbb
cca
```

than print out

```
2
1
0
```

because

- 'aaa' is 2 times
- 'bbb' is 1 times
- 'cca' is 0 times

```
 if( strcmp(str2[i], str1[j]) == 0) cnt++;
```

however the if statement, doesn't count `cnt++`

whats wrong,  my code with strcmp() ?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables called `cnt`.

One declared on this line:

```
int N, Q, cnt;
```

and scoped to the entire function.

One declared on this line:

```
for(int j=0, cnt=0; j<N; j++) {
```

and scoped to the `for` loop.

The statement `cnt++` modifies the second one since it's inside the for loop.

The statement `printf("%d\n", cnt);` prints the first one since it's outside the for loop.

Comment: There are not two variable, cnt. i am 100% sure. can you check again?

Comment: @alexparkjw There are two variable, cnt. I am 150% sure, can you check again?

Comment: Because i check, and i changed the if code like  if( strcmp(str2[i], str1[j]) == 0) printf("123\n");  but never print out 123

Comment: `int j=0, cnt=0` declares two variables, `j` and `cnt` and initialises them. It does not delare and initialise `j` and then set the existing variable `cnt` to zero. This is called variable shadowing and compilers can warn you about it if you instruct them to do so.

Comment: @doesn't matter cnt is two or tree.  ~  for(int i=0; i<Q; i++) {
        cnt=0;
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            // if statement 
            if( strcmp(str2[i], str1[j]) == 0) cnt++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", cnt);
    }

Comment: @alexparkjw Then maybe you have two problems, and *one* of the problems is that you have two different variables called `cnt`.